# $\mathbb Z_p^*$ is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb Z_p^*$ ($p$ prime) is a group using the Fermat's little theorem to show that every element is invertible.

Thus using the Fermat's little theorem, for each $a\in Z_p^*$, we have $a^{p-1}\equiv1$ (mod p). The problem is to prove that p-1 is the least positive integer which $a^{p-1}\equiv1$ (mod p).

**Remark:** $\mathbb Z_p^*$ is $\{\overline 1,...,\overline {p-1}\}$ with multiplication.

I need help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why should it be the least positive integer? You have just proved that $\overline{x}^{-1}=\overline{x}^{p-2}$, which gives the inverse.

Comment: As far as I know, this notation is for the [group of units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)) of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$. So it is a group. But it turns out that $\mathbb{Z}_p^*=\{a\in\mathbb{Z}_p\;;\; a\neq 0\}$. That is: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field. And that is what you are trying to prove: every nonzero element is invertible.

Comment: @egreg yes, you're right, I didn't think in this way. Thank you very much

Comment: @julien yes, I know, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't show that $p-1$ is the least positive integer $r$ such that $a^r\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, because in general it isn't: for instance, the least integer for $a=1$ is $1$.

But all you need is to find an element which acts as an inverse:

$$a\cdot a^{p-2} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$

so that, for any $\overline{x}\in\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ you have

$$\overline{x}\cdot\overline{x}^{\,p-2} = \overline{1}$$

and so

$$\overline{x}^{\,-1}=\overline{x}^{\,p-2}$$

Comment: I have a question. How can we know that $\overline{x}^{\,-1}=\overline{x}^{\,p-2} \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}$? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @nameless $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ is a group (with respect to multiplication) and has $p-1$ elements. If a group $G$ has $n$ elements, then $g^n=1$ for any $g\in G$ and therefore $g^{-1}=g^{n-1}$.

Comment: Yes. Now, we want to show $(\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}, \cdot)$ is a group.  For show it has an inverse, we find $\overline{x}^{p-2}$ such that $\overline{x}\cdot\overline{x}^{\,p-2} = \overline{1}$. But we need to show that $\overline{x}^{p-2}$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}$ ?

Comment: I want to ask a clarifying question: is it by Fermat’s little problem that the inverse of $a$ is $a^{p-2}$ and not $a^{p-1}$? I guess I’m confused because thought every element in $\mathbb{F}^{*}_{p}$ still has order $p$ and not $p-1$. But maybe I’m wrong. If it were $(\mathbb{F}_p, +)$, then the order is $p$, and $(\mathbb{F}_p^{*}, \times)$, then the order if $p-1$.

Comment: @cheeseboardqueen Neither “order $p$” nor “order $p-1$” is true. If $a\not\equiv0\pmod{p}$, then $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$ by Euler-Fermat, sometimes referred to as Fermat's little theorem, which actually says that $a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$. So no element has order $p$. Nor the order is necessarily $p-1$, but a divisor thereof; anyway, for $a\not\equiv0$, we have $aa^{p-2}\equiv1$, so $a^{p-2}$ is the inverse of $a$ modulo $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Please check my inverse solution.

Let $\overline{x} \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}^*$. Then $(x,p)=1$, that is there exist $k, q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $kx + qp=1$. This implies $\overline{k}\overline{x}=\overline{1}$. Suppose that $\overline{k}=\overline{0}$. Then $\overline{0}=\overline{1}$, a contradict. Thus $\overline{k} \not = \overline{0}$, so $k \not = 0$.

Now, we write $k=mp+r$ where $0 \leq r < p$. If $k<p$, then $(k,p)=1$. It follows that $\overline{k} \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}^*$. If $k=p$, then $r=0$. It follows that $\overline{k}=\overline{0}$, a contradict, thus $k \not = p$. If $k>p$, then we have $k=mp+r$ where $0 < r < p$. Hence $\overline{r} \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$. Since $k \equiv r \, (\mod p)$, $\overline{k} \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$.

Therefore $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ has inverse.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I made an Isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}^*_p = \{1,2,3,...,p-1\}$ and all the Automorphisms of a Group G of order p which is of the form $\varphi_{x}(g)=g^{x}$ (Where $x \in \mathbb{Z}^*_p$ and $g \in G$, I hope you can know the demonstration of this first part). That's the key, due to G is of prime order, that's cyclic with no subgroups, I said $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}^*_p, \varphi_{x}(g) = g^{x} \neq e$.
And now, you know that all Automorphism made a group under composition and  $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^*_p, \varphi_{x}  \circ \varphi_{y} = \varphi_{xy}$ then $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$ is a group too!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).